# Unit testing SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, stored-procedures

I am trying to follow this:

[Unit Testing SQL Server sproc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851212%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

I am using Visual Studio 2010 but cannot find the option to add a unit test to the imported stored procedures - see this step:

> Right-click one of the stored procedures, and click Create Unit Tests to display the Create Unit Tests dialog box.

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: The link is about SQL Server Data Tools. Have you installed them? Did you create a database project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you provide is about [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx), a separate download. You need to install SSDT and then create a Database Project

After installed, the context menu is only available in Visual Studio's SQL Server Object Explorer (which can be accessed as a window under the View menu). Expand your project's Programmability folder and then finally right click on Stored Procedures.

Comment: Thanks - I knew I was missing something (-:

Comment: mmh I still cannot see the option of adding a unit test to a sproc ... any ideas?

Comment: Are you clicking on the stored procedure under the Projects node in SQL Server Object Explorer? The option isn't currently available on files containing sprocs in solution explorer. Also, the project needs to build without errors or else the option will be grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with the "Create Unit Tests" being disabled it came down to this important point - so I deleted everything that would not build.

"...the project needs to build without errors or else the option will be grayed out. – Kevin Cunnane Dec 25 '13 at 14:05"